# objective-c ios auto layout NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

```
UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, frameWidth, frameHeight)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x5F70B9);
    
    UIImage* leftImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"search_list"];
    UIImageView* leftImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: leftImage];
    [leftImageView setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 15, 70, 50)]; // CGRectMake(10, 15, 70, 50)

    UITextView* textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 20, 160, 40)];
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x5F70B9);
    textView.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFFFFFF);
    [textView setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleTitle3]];
    textView.text = STLocalizedString(@"message_overall_non_reply");
    textView.editable = NO;
    
    UIImage* rightImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"arrow_mask"];
    UIImageView* rightImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: rightImage];
    [rightImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(380, 30, 15, 20)];
    
    [headerView addSubview: leftImageView];
    [headerView addSubview: textView];
    [headerView addSubview: rightImageView];
```

Expect image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i590Z.png)

Now i am hardcoding the origin x, y and everything. I want to use auto layout so that the left image and right image act as leading and trailing icon.

any suggestion?

Tried something like below, but not working:
`

```
[leftImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

NSLayoutConstraint *leftImageViewConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: leftImage attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: headerView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier: 1 constant: 0];

[leftImageView addConstraints: @[leftImageViewConstraint]];
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate each constraint that you add. When you have a bunch of constraints to set it's a lot easier to use `NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints`. And using the various "anchor" properties for setting up the constraints is simpler than using the long form of creating an `NSLayoutConstraint`.

Here's your code updated with lots of constraints:

```
UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, frameWidth, frameHeight)];
headerView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x5F70B9);

UIImage* leftImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"search_list"];
UIImageView* leftImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: leftImage];

UITextView* textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
textView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x5F70B9);
textView.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFFFFFF);
textView.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleTitle3];
textView.text = STLocalizedString(@"message_overall_non_reply");
textView.editable = NO;

UIImage* rightImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"arrow_mask"];
UIImageView* rightImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: rightImage];

leftImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
rightImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[headerView addSubview: leftImageView];
[headerView addSubview: textView];
[headerView addSubview: rightImageView];

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [leftImageView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.leadingAnchor constant:10],
    //[leftImageView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.topAnchor constant:15],
    [leftImageView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.centerYAnchor],
    [leftImageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:70],
    [leftImageView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:50],
    [rightImageView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.trailingAnchor constant:-10],
    //[rightImageView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.topAnchor constant:30],
    [rightImageView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.centerYAnchor],
    [rightImageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:15],
    [rightImageView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:20],
    [textView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:leftImageView.trailingAnchor constant:10],
    [textView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:rightImageView.leadingAnchor constant:-10],
    [textView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.topAnchor constant:20],
    [textView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.bottomAnchor constant:-20],
]];
```

I made a few guesses here. Obviously you can change these to suit your needs.